# Tabbed Activity - Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I want to create a "Tabbed Activity" with tabs for make a user-friendly layout. I've already set the activity to work with PagerAdapter

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    toolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(Color.BLUE);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Chat"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Appunti"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_yahweh));


    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
}
}
```

And then there is PagerAdapter

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
            return tab2;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```

And finally, TabFragment1 code

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "ChatActivity";

private ChatArrayAdapter adp;
private ListView list;
private EditText chatText;
private Button send;
Intent intent;

private boolean side = false;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
}

public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_fragment_1);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adp = new ChatArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.chat);

        list.setAdapter(adp);
        chatText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chat_text);
        chatText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                    return sendChatMessage();
                }

                return false;

            }

        });

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                sendChatMessage();
            }

        });


        list.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);

        list.setAdapter(adp);
        adp.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {


            public void OnChanged(){
                super.onChanged();
                list.setSelection(adp.getCount() -1);
            }

        });


    }


    private boolean sendChatMessage(){

        adp.add(new ChatMessage(side, chatText.getText().toString()));

        chatText.setText("");
        side = !side;
        return true;

    }

}
}
```

And tab_fragment_1 XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/chat_text"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn"
            />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chat_text"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I get a lot of errors on TabFragment1.java, so i was wondering what i was doing bad. Then i found that getIntent(), setContentView, findViewById, getApplicationContext() are all related to an Activity, and cannot be called from a Fragment. So i tried to change my TabFragment1.java. Now it appears like this

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {

private ChatArrayAdapter adp;
private EditText chatText;
private boolean side = false;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
    EditText chatText = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.chat_text);
    Button send = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    ListView list = (ListView) root.findViewById (R.id.listview);
    list.setAdapter(adp);
    adp = new ChatArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.chat);
    list.setAdapter(adp);

    chatText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                return sendChatMessage();
            }

            return false;

        }
    });

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            sendChatMessage();

        }
    });

    list.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
    list.setAdapter(adp);
    adp.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {

    });
return root;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


private boolean sendChatMessage(){

        adp.add(new ChatMessage(side, chatText.getText().toString()));
        chatText.setText("");
        side = !side;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And i still get an error when i try to send a message on my app. It says:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

What i've done bad?

Comment: Second button in the java paclahe, new/Fragment. You  can guide your self with the code in the TabbedActivity selected from the Gallery. Inside that Activity there is a PagerAdapter,  there you can add your Fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shadowed your EditText field

Replace

```
EditText chatText = (EditText) root.findViewById
```

With

```
this.chatText = (EditText) root.findViewById
```

fyi, tabbed activities aren't deprecated

Comment: First, thank you very much: it worked!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Third. Why i hadn't to add (this) to Button send = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        ListView list = (ListView) root.findViewById (R.id.listview); ???